# Como adicionar valores em uma nova column de uma table de relacionamento ManyToMany? (ADONIS.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, relacionamento, adonisjs

tudo bem?
Estou iniciando no adonis e tenho um problema ao tentar inserir novos valores na table pelo adonis...

Tenho um relacionamento manyToMany entre as tables contracts e workplaces. Com isso tenho uma nova table contract_workplace que recebe id de contracts e workplaces. Até aí, tudo bem. Estava conseguindo criar novos contracts e relacionar normalmente com workplaces. Porém agora precisei inserir uma nova coluna (num_aulas) dentro da table contract_workplace e queria inserir o valor nela ao criar num novo contract. **(Obs.: Criei a migration normalmente e rodou perfeitamente. Consigo inserir os dados diretamente no DB. Só pelo insomnia que está retornando esse erro...)**
Tentei passar um object com workplace_id e num_aulas, mas está dando erro na query... Segue o erro:

```
"workplaces": [{"workplace_id": 7, "num_aulas": 10}] //forma de envio via insomia(formato JSON)



"message": "insert into `workplaces_contracts` (`contract_id`, `workplace_id`) values (56, '{\\\"workplace_id\\\":7,\\\"num_aulas\\\":10}') - ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '{\"workplace_id\":7,\"num_aulas\":10}' for column 'workplace_id' at row 1",
```

Entendi que a query está errada, pois não está incluindo o value de num_aulas e está enviando o object na column workplace_id. Deveria ser:

```
INSERT INTO `workplaces_contracts` (`workplace_id`, `contract_id`, `num_aulas`) VALUES (5, 26, 10);
```

Não sei porque, não está incluindo automaticamente...

segue abaixo como criei o relacionamento no Model de Contracts:

```
  @manyToMany(() => Workplace, {
    pivotTable: 'workplaces_contracts',
    pivotColumns: ['workplace_id', 'num_aulas']
  })
  public workplaces: ManyToMany<typeof Workplace>
```

segue abaixo como tentei inserir o valor de num_aulas no método store no Controller de Contracts:

```
public async store({ request, response }: HttpContextContract) {

        const contractSchema = schema.create({
            type: schema.enum(Object.values(contractsType)),
            number: schema.string(),
            registration: schema.string(),
            occupation: schema.string(),
            siope_category: schema.string(),
            weekly_hours: schema.number(),
            replacement_reason: schema.string(),
            start_period: schema.date(),
            end_period: schema.date.optional(),
            status: schema.boolean.optional(),
            person_id: schema.number(),
            workplaces: schema.array().members(schema.object().members({
                workplace_id: schema.number(),
                num_aulas: schema.number()
            }))
        })




        try {
            await request.validate({ schema: contractSchema })
        } catch (error) {
            return response.badRequest(error.messages)
        }

        const contract: Contract = await Contract.create(
            lodash.mapKeys(request.all(), (_: any, key: any) => lodash.camelCase(key))
        )

        await contract.related('workplaces').attach(request.body().workplaces)

        return response.json(contract)


    }
```

Forma de envio no insomnia

```
{
    "type": "CONTRATO",
    "number": "2048/2023",
    "registration": "45202",
    "occupation": "Monitor I (CA)",
    "siope_category": "15 - todos2",
    "weekly_hours": 1002,
    "replacement_reason": "Ensino Medio2",
    "start_period": "2013-12-13",
    "status": 1,
    "person_id": 4,
    "workplaces": [{"workplace_id": 7, "num_aulas": 10}]
```

}